# Notepad++: highlighting characters of a line (Intel HEX-file highliting)

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I have the problem to highlight the Intel HEX-file syntax.

- The 1. character of a line is ":"
- The 2. to 3. character of a line should be in a different color (2 chars)
- The 4. to 7. character of a line should be in a different color     (4)
- The 8. to 9. character of a line should be in a different color     (2)
- The 10. to xx. character of a line should be in a different color   (x)
- and then until ((EOL)) the last color.

Can it be maybe done with Delimiters?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be possible with the current implementation of User Defined Languages in Notepad++.

In order to support custom syntax highlighting, the language needs to be defined with keywords, delimiters and operators.

Since Intel HEX files don't separate the numbers, Notepad++ will treat the entire line as a single number.

There is more information about User Defined Languages [in the documentation](https://ivan-radic.github.io/udl-documentation).